# Fetching data from excel sheet in python

Tags: python

I am importing inputs from excel and I want to check if each input value is within the given range in if condition. but the problem is that the code stop at the row which is a satisfied and print warning and does not take the next rows to check if any other row is also in the range.

```
# importing openpyxl module
import openpyxl

# workbook object is created
workbook1 = openpyxl.load_workbook("edges.coordinates.xlsx")
workbook2 = openpyxl.load_workbook("sensors data.xlsx")
#For sheet1
sheet_obj1 = workbook1["sheet1"]
#For sheet2
sheet_obj2 = workbook1["sheet2"]
#for sensors sheeta
sheet_obj3 = workbook2["sheet1"]

# Will print a particular row value
for j in range(1, sheet_obj3.max_row):
  #Fetching Data From Cell For Sheet1/workbook 2
  x= sheet_obj3.cell(row = 1+j, column = 1).value
  y = sheet_obj3.cell(row = 1+j, column = 2).value
  z = sheet_obj3.cell(row = 1+j, column = 3).value

# Will print a particular row value
  for i in range(1, sheet_obj1.max_row):
  #Fetching Data From Cell For Sheet1
    x1 = sheet_obj1.cell(row = i, column = 1)
    y1 = sheet_obj1.cell(row = i, column = 2)
    x2 = sheet_obj1.cell(row = i+1, column = 1)
    y2 = sheet_obj1.cell(row = i+1, column = 2)
    z1 = sheet_obj1.cell(row = i, column = 3)

    #Fetching Data From Cell For Sheet2
    x11 = sheet_obj2.cell(row = i, column = 1)
    y11 = sheet_obj2.cell(row = i, column = 2)
    x22 = sheet_obj2.cell(row = i+1, column = 1)
    y22 = sheet_obj2.cell(row = i+1, column = 2)

  #Printing Warning If Condition Is Satisfied
    if z == z1.value:
         if min(x1.value,x2.value,x11.value,x22.value)<=x <=max(x1.value,x2.value,x11.value,x22.value) and  min(y1.value,y2.value,y11.value,y22.value)<=y<=max(y1.value,y2.value,y11.value,y22.value):
             print("Warning Between Row"+str(i)+" and Row"+str((i+1)))2
```

Comment: Are you getting a runtime error? In the code you posted there is an extraneous “2” at the end of your print statement

Comment: No its working. But when row1 in excel satisfies the condition. It doesn't check wether the any of the row2 ,3,4...satisfies the condition or not. It stopped when the first row is satisfied

Comment: With having any data to work with it is difficult to provide an answer. I don’t see anything wrong with your code other than the extra “2” which has to be throwing an error. Try adding print(i, j) just above “if z == z1.value:” to confirm how many iterations it goes through.